# how to unmarshall objects to particular type by identifying its type form xml?

Tags: java, stream

I have a server and a client, server is basically a CEP(complex event processing system) which receives
multiple streams of sensor data in the form of POJO(plain old java objects). Client generates this data and send it to server over LAN. I decided to create POJO of each type of sensor data, marshall it and send it to server from client.

now problem is identifying which sensor type data received at server and unmarshalling to that type of object.

Please someone help, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the code on the server then probably create a property e.g opCode in each of your pojo from the client.Then on the server use this opCode to differentiate between different types of sensor data and then unmarshal to the required object.